# How do you use context in classes?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.lala.image;

import com.lala.ContextStore;

import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;

public class Stationary implements Image{

    View v;
    Context context;
    String image;
    Bitmap img;

    float x;
    float y;


    public Stationary(Context context, String image) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.image = image;
        this.context = context;
        this.setImage(image);
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(image=="bdfs"){
            this.img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.icon);
        }
        else if(image=="ssdfsdf"){
            this.img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.icon); 
        }
        else if(image=="asfdsdf"){
            this.img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.icon); 
        }
        else{
            this.img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.icon); 
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getImage(){
        return img;
    }

    public float getX() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.y;
    }

    public void setX(float x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(float y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

I am not sure how to use context and resources in a class when it is called from another activity.

I am getting an error message when the context or resources are called.

Any code to assist would be very welcome.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is not with the context but with the way you're calling `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`.  I see you're passing in `R.id.icon` which is an ID of an element in a layout.  You need to pass in a reference to an image.  Something like `R.drawable.your_bitmap` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info, changed the code, the .icon part of the R.drawable.icon is highlighted red with error "icon cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: You need to add the image file to the res/drawable folder and rename to icon.

Comment: Thanks you've helped me lots there